# Is there a way to use an array passed as parameter on std::begin or std::end?

Tags: c++

I keep getting a compilation error if I use an array passed as parameter to a method on std::begin or std::end such as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    static bool exists(int ints[], int size, int k)
    {
        if (std::find(std::begin(ints), std::end(ints), k) != std::end(ints)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

I tried casting it to &int[0] but it will still not compile.

Comment: Despite looking like an array parameter, `int ints[]` is not an arary parameter.

Comment: if you convert your array of int to an `std::vetcor<int>` then it is straight forward.

Comment: Nope, but you can just use pointers since you have the size. https://godbolt.org/z/38fbr6Wec

Comment: You could use `std::span` instead of pointer and size

Comment: show the rest of the code and i can show you how to use `std::array` instead :)

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `ints` is not an array, so you aren't passing an array into `std::begin` / `std::end` in the example. A function parameter is never an array in C++. When you declare a function array to be an array such as in your example, that parameter is adjusted to be a pointer to the element of such array. In your case, the type of the parameter `ints` has been adjusted to be a pointer to `int` i.e. `int*`, and you cannot pass a pointer into `std::begin` / `std::end`, as the error message surely explains.

You have passed the `size` as another parameter, so you could instead use:

```
std::find(ints, ints + size, k)
```

---

A more modern API design is to wrap the pointer and the size into a single class. The C++20 standard library comes with such class template: `std::span`. It also has convenient range algorithms that are quite convenient:

```
static bool exists(std::span<const int> ints, int k)
{
    if (std::ranges::find(ints, k) != std::end(ints)) {
```

Even moreso, C++20 standard library has a function template that makes your function unnecessary:

```
std::ranges::contains(some_array, k);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::span`.

try this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

bool exists(std::span<int> span, int needle) {
  return std::find(span.begin(), span.end(), needle) != span.end();
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  bool ok = exists(arr, 3);
  if (ok) {
    std::cout << "ok" << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "not ok" << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
bool exists(int x[], const  int size, const int k)
{
    std::vector<int> v(x, x + size);
    if (std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), k) != v.end()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    int const sz = 10;
    int arrayi[sz] = { 1, 2, 3,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 , 8, 9, 0 };
    if (exists(arrayi, sz, 4))
        std::cout << "exist" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "it does not" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Creating std::vector from "array" is unneeded, `std::find(x, x + size, k)` would be better.